# How to make a jslider enable/disable or make visible/not visible text boxes in Java?

Tags: java, textbox, jslider

I am working with jsliders, I have made a jslider, and couple of text boxes, what I want to do is when lets say the user slides the slider to 3 it makes visible text boxes. I have a code which is working at the moment and also does not interpret making visible text boxes but enabling or disabling them.

```
do {
            textField.setEnabled(true);
            }
         while (slider.setValue(3));
```

I want to hide text boxes and when the user slides the slider to 3 it enables text boxes. Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a change listener like

```
jSlider1.addChangeListener(new javax.swing.event.ChangeListener() {
        public void stateChanged(javax.swing.event.ChangeEvent evt) {
            jSlider1StateChanged(evt);
        }
    });
```

and then change the visibility of the text field on that function:

```
private void jSlider1StateChanged(javax.swing.event.ChangeEvent evt) {                                      
    if(jSlider1.getValue()<50)
        jLabel1.setVisible(false);
    else
        jLabel1.setVisible(true);   
}
```

Comment: Hi, I implemented the code according to my needs (change of names of the components), it looks like this now; slider.addChangeListener(new javax.swing.event.ChangeListener() {
         public void stateChanged(javax.swing.event.ChangeEvent evt) {
             sliderStateChanged(evt);
         }
     });
  
  private void sliderStateChanged(javax.swing.event.ChangeEvent evt) {                                      
      if(slider.getValue() == 5)
          textField.setVisible(false);
      else
          textField.setVisible(true);   
  }

Comment: **The error I am getting now is where it says sliderStateChanged(evt), it tells me to remove the slider and also the sliderStateChanged in the private void is giving an error.**